# Join PySpark dataframes on substring match (or contains)

Tags: pyspark

I would like to perform a left join between two dataframes, but the columns don't match identically. The join column in the first dataframe has an extra suffix relative to the second dataframe.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

sc = SparkContext()

df1 = sc.parallelize([
    ['AB-101-1', 'el1', 1.5],
    ['ABC-1020-1', 'el2', 1.3],
    ['AC-1030-1', 'el3', 8.5]
]).toDF(('id1', 'el', 'v1'))

df2 = sc.parallelize([
    ['AB-101', 3],
    ['ABC-1020', 4]
]).toDF(('id2', 'v2'))
```

The dataframe I would like to get as a result of the left join is:

```
df_join = sc.parallelize([
    ['AB-101-1', 'el1', 1.5, 'AB-101', 3],
    ['ABC-1020-1', 'el2', 1.3, 'ABC-1020', 4],
    ['AC-103-1', 'el3', 8.5, None, None]
]).toDF(('id1', 'el', 'v1', 'id2', 'v2'))
```

I would be happy to use `pyspark.sql.substring` to take "all except the final 2 characters", or to use something like `pyspark.sql.like`, but I can't figure out how to make either of these work properly inside the join.

Comment: I posted a limited solution as an answer below but I would happily accept a more general answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `id1` & `id2` have some pattern similar to what you have illustrated in your question then I would suggest below approach.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract

df1 = sc.parallelize([
    ['AB-101-1', 'el1', 1.5],
    ['ABC-1020-1', 'el2', 1.3],
    ['AC-1030-1', 'el3', 8.5]
]).toDF(('id1', 'el', 'v1'))

df2 = sc.parallelize([
    ['AB-101', 3],
    ['ABC-1020', 4]
]).toDF(('id2', 'v2'))

df1 = df1.withColumn("id1_transformed", regexp_extract('id1', '(.*-.*)(-.*)', 1))

df_join = df1.join(df2, df1.id1_transformed==df2.id2, 'left').drop("id1_transformed")
df_join.show()
```

Output is:

```
+----------+---+---+--------+----+
|       id1| el| v1|     id2|  v2|
+----------+---+---+--------+----+
|ABC-1020-1|el2|1.3|ABC-1020|   4|
|  AB-101-1|el1|1.5|  AB-101|   3|
| AC-1030-1|el3|8.5|    null|null|
+----------+---+---+--------+----+
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

In your specific case, `regexp_extract` is probably your best option, but in the general case you can use:

```
df_join = df1.join(df2, df2.id2.contains(df1.id1), how='left')
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses `split` to deconstruct the original `id1` and then `concat` to rebuild the shorter `id2`.

```
df1 = (
    df1
    .withColumn('id1_els', f.split('id1','-'))
    .withColumn('id2', 
                f.concat(f.col('id1_els').getItem(0)
                         , f.lit('-')
                         , f.col('id1_els').getItem(1)))
)

df_join = df1.join(df2, 'id2', 'left').show()
```

But I would rather use a solution with `substring` or `contains`, because this depends heavily on the specific form of my ID field.