# Hive SQL left join based on substring search from a second table

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hql

I need to create a table that joins queries with a set of keywords that we are targeting within our content. The Google Search table is search queries and impressions to the blog and the keyword table is an internally created table of keywords and a value (1-10) we assign to them. I need to join these two in order to get the impressions based on keywords.

something similar to this dummy code

```
   select a.*, b.* 
     from google_search_table a
left join Keyword_Table b
       on contains(a.query, b.keyword)
```

Google Search Table

| Query | Impressions |
| --- | --- |
| Most minty toothpaste | 8274 |
| best bath soap | 4375 |
| How to cook tomatoes | 1734 |
| top softest toilet paper | 892 |
| top bushcraft skills | 9284 |

Keyword Table

| Keyword | value |
| --- | --- |
| toothpaste | 2 |
| soap | 5 |
| tomatoes | 3 |
| toilet paper | 3 |

Intended Result Table

| Keyword | Impressions |
| --- | --- |
| toothpaste | 8274 |
| soap | 4375 |
| tomatoes | 1734 |
| toilet paper | 892 |
| null | 9284 |

Answer (score 0):

Here's the SQL to solve your problem.

```
SELECT * 
from ( select Keyword, Impressions
from google_search_table
lateral view explode(split(Query,' ')) t1 as Keyword ) a
where 
  a.Keyword is in (select Keyword from Keyword_Table)
```

If that performs reasonably, great use it.  I'm assuming the keyword table is small.

If it blows the memory stack you may want to look at some type of broadcast join or map side join.

Comment: This is great but doesn't work for 2-word keywords (probably should be called key phrases). For example, "toilet paper", row 4 of the keyword table. It would split all the queries into rows with only 1 word per row. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Your totally correct it would not work for "key phrases" only key words.  (I totally missed the very clear 2 word example you included) 
You likely need to use spark function/hive UDF to do the 'contains' in a clean way.  UDF aren't the best in performance but they'll get the job done.  Spark is likely the simplest to way to write something to solve the issue over creating a java class as a UDF.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying pyspark/spark

```
resultTable = google_search_table.join(Keyword_Table, google_search_table.Query.contains(Keyword_Table.Keyword), how='left')
```

You can see how someone else solved a [similar issue using pyspark here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45551417/join-pyspark-dataframes-on-substring-match-or-contains).

Comment: Hmm. this is new to me. I'll give it a shot. Thanks.